# Scraping Product Names using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup (BS4) to build a scraper tool that will allow me to pull the product name from any TopShop.com product page, which sits between 'h1' tags. Can't figure out why the  code I've written isn't working!

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

TopShop_URL = raw_input("Enter a TopShop Product URL")
ProductPage = urlopen(TopShop_URL).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(ProductPage)

ProductNames = soup.find_all('h1')

print ProductNames
```

Comment: One problem is that your code is generating a SyntaxError on the last line: http://ideone.com/ByfJ7K

Comment: How "isn't it working"? How are the results you're seeing different from what you expect?

Comment: @bernie not seeing a Syntax error on my end. Expecting to scrape data between H1 tags but the above doesn't seem to return anything. I am very new to Python, finding my feet.

Comment: If you don't have a syntax error that means you're not running this on Python 3 and the question is inappropriately tagged.

Comment: You are right, I'm on 2.7. Sorry.

Comment: No problem. I fixed the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get this working using requests (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

content = requests.get("TOPShop_URL").content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
product_names = soup.findAll("h1")
print product_names
```

Comment: This is assuming there is only one h1 tag

Comment: Thx for your help. I tried this out but am told I need an external parser (lxml or html5lib). I'll give that a shot and see how it goes. Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, but the problem is that the div which includes the product name is dynamically generated via JavaScript.
In order to be able to successfully parse this element you should mind using [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) or a similar tool, that will allow you to parse the webpage after all the dom has been fully loaded.